# Angular4/Ionic3 how to Serializer data

Tags: angular, authentication, ionic3, token, serialization

I'm working in app with ionic 3 / Angular 4 and I have a problem with log-in function.
I want change the json format from this:

```
> this.data = {
>               grant_type: "password",
>               username: this.loginData.username,
>               password: this.loginData.password,
>               client_id: "client"
>               };
```

to something like this

> ?grant_type=password&client_id=client&client_secret=secret&username=admin&password=123456

so I can use it for token authentication like that:

> http://localhost:8080/api/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=client&client_secret=secret&username=admin&password=123456

I used it in ionic 1 / angularJS like that

> data: $httpParamSerializer($scope.data);

but I don't know the equivalent in angular 4.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use [**URLSearchParams**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/URLSearchParams-class.html)

Basic example

```
let params = new URLSearchParams();
params.set('search', term); // the user's search value
```

[**Set Search Parameters**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#search-parameters)

**Your Service**

```
import { Headers, RequestOptions, Http, Response, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';


// User is done editing, serialize and POST to web service
tokenAuthenticate(): void {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    // Dynamically serialize the entire object
    // *** THIS IS THE SERIALIZATION ***
    let params: URLSearchParams = this.serialize(this.selectedItem);


    this._http.post('http://localhost:8080/api/oauth/token', params, options)
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);

}

/**
 * Serializes the form element so it can be passed to the back end through the url.
 * The objects properties are the keys and the objects values are the values.
 * ex: { "a":1, "b":2, "c":3 } would look like ?a=1&b=2&c=3
 * @param obj - Object to be url encoded
 * @returns URLSearchParams - The url encoded system setup
 */
serialize(obj: any): URLSearchParams {
    let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();

    for (var key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var element = obj[key];

            params.set(key, element);
        }
    }
    return params;
}
```

Comment: for function <serialize(obj: SystemSetup)> : SystemSetup not knowing, I must change to what? or I need import something??

Comment: You can change it to any

Comment: Okey Thanks works fine but I got a new error : "error":"Unauthorized","message":"Full authentication is required to access this resource"

Comment: It's not back end problem. It's just a problem of syntax on log-in function and It's work fine now. Thanks for your reply :)